# Why are declarations put between func() and {}?

Tags: c

In sed source I saw often

```
func(...)
int b;
char c;

{
...
}
```

Why put variables there? Does it change the scope?

Like here: http://www.mirrors.docunext.com/lxr/http/source/src/bin/sed/lib/regex_internal.c?v=haiku

```
re_string_allocate (pstr, str, len, init_len, trans, icase, dfa)
 51      re_string_t *pstr;
 52      const char *str;
 53      int len, init_len, icase;
 54      RE_TRANSLATE_TYPE trans;
 55      const re_dfa_t *dfa;
 56 {
 57   reg_errcode_t ret;
 58   int init_buf_len;
 59
```

Comment: Eek, K&R declarations!

Comment: +1, I learned something new today. I didn't even know this existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just old style, pre-ANSI C. The whole notion of function declarations with type parameters wasn't introduced until later!

Answer (score 3):

This is K&R (old) style, it works, but..

Answer (score 3):

That's just the old [(K&R)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) way of declaring parameters in C.

```
/* Old way of declaring parameters*/
void myFunc(a, b)
  int a; int b;
{
    ...
}
```

Nobody does it that way anymore, unless you need to compile your code on a *really* old compiler - so either sed was written with old compilers in mind, or that code is really old.