# In C, what does it mean when I declare a variable following a function signature, before the function body?

Tags: c, function, syntax, compiler-errors, method-signature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are declarations put between func() and {}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491026/why-are-declarations-put-between-func-and)

In C, what does it mean when I declare a variable following a function signature, before the function body?

Example:

```
int foo (i) int i {
    printf ("the value of variable 'i' is: %d", i);
    return i;
}
```

When I compile the the code in addition to initializing variable i, I get a compile error:
"cannot initialize parameter: p"

Comment: It means _ancient_ code, since C89, the proper way is `int foo(int i) { ...`.

Comment: I almost hate to ask, which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you are looking at old code.
That is the old K&R syntax.
Basically it says, **i** is the argument, and it is an **int**

You can rewrite it as

```
int foo (int i) 
{
    printf ("the value of variable 'i' is: %d", i);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Actually, "ancient" is the better word here.  I doubt you'll even find much (any?) old DOS code that uses the original K & R parameter declarations like that :)

Comment: I have a few in my archive :)  Humm.... 1980 something.... In college.  Unix on a Z8000 if i recall correctly.

Comment: @paulsm4 I have just found an astronimic library which uses this notation and compiles with x64 MinGW 5.4.0 well at the same time.  http://www.moshier.net/aadoc.html

Comment: Why are you necromancing a five year old post?  If you've found an old library and it compiles and works for you - great.  But PLEASE don't try to write any NEW code using decades-obsolete syntax.  OK?